# nav role=navigation

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm a little confused with roles. If I have in my page a navigation that is enclosed in a `nav` element and specify a `role="navigation"`.

```
<nav role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>
```

Isn't it already semantically explicit that the `nav` section is navigation?

Or if I have some other navigation sections on my page, and specify role for only one of them, this section becomes the most important on a page? And those without `role="navigation"` just boring navigations?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is true that most modern browsers/technologies recognise the HTML5 `<nav>` element as navigation and give it the same attention. But explicitly setting the `role="navigation"` attribute just makes sure that a lot more technologies can pick it up.

For example screen-readers and other technologies for users with disabilities are very rarely fully standards compliant (especially if they have to work all the way back to IE6 or lower!) so adding the role attributes explicitly always ensures that you cover all your bases for the most users possible.

Also (and this is just a guess) some of the lesser known search engines may not fully recognise HTML5 yet, so adding these roles should help with the sites crawl-ability.

Comment: I don’t think there is any evidence of any search engines “recognizing HTML5” (like `nav`), even less ARIA.

Comment: True there is no "evidence" because the details of search engine methods are so secret, but the mark-up is available to help recognise the page structure. I hate assumptions but with search engine tech they are sometimes a necessary evil - so I assume they will be using all of the tools at their disposal to display the best results, and we should also do everything we can to help them do it.

Comment: In regards to your second question, the different priorities and the other in's and out's of roles, I suggest you do some research on the subject as there is a lot of information out there. There is a nice overview [here](http://alistapart.com/article/aria-and-progressive-enhancement) that should be able to get you started. You could even delve into the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) if needs be.

Comment: In addition, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#wai-aria for default mappings.

Comment: In 2021, Mozilla says: "Using the <nav> element will automatically communicate a section has a role of navigation. Developers should always prefer using the correct semantic HTML element over using ARIA." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Navigation_Role)

Answer (score 22):

Take a look [at this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sec-strong-native-semantics) from W3C. It says:

> In the *majority* of cases setting an ARIA role and/or aria-* attribute
>   that matches the default implicit ARIA semantics is *unnecessary and
>   not recommended* as these properties are already set by the browser.

So doing `<main role="main">` is *unnecessary and not recommended*. That said, the [Bootstrap's navbar examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) (which everybody -including me- copy-pastes) come with `<nav role="navigation">`.

To be honest, I'm not sure what's correct.

Comment: not anymore, it seems - the example currently reads `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` - btw, the [w3c validator also warns about this](https://validator.w3.org/nu/): 'Warning: Element nav does not need a role attribute.'

Comment: @maxschlepzig I haven't used Bootstrap in the last year. Feel free to edit the question!

Comment: [Bootstrap v4 alpha 6](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/): _"Ensure accessibility by using a <nav> element or, if using a more generic element such as a <div>, add a role="navigation" to every navbar to explicitly identify it as a landmark region for users of assistive technologies."_

Answer (score 5):

W3C recommends: "However, in order to make the structure more accessible to user agents that support ARIA as well as ensuring that user agents that don't support HTML5 can also understand the structure, adding the ARIA role="navigation" is advised."
https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_nav_element

Answer (score 3):

Using the `<nav>` element will automatically communicate that a section has the role of `navigation`. Developers should always prefer using the correct semantic HTML element over ARIA.

Source: [MDN Article on ARIA: Navigation Role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Navigation_Role)